# A property of a solution of a differential problem.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f \in L^2(0,1)$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$ a.e. in $(-1,1)$ and let $u$ be the solution of the problem

$$ -u''(x)+u(x)=f(x) \,\,\,\, x \in (-1,1)$$
with the condition
$$ u(-1)=u(1)=0 $$

Can I deduce that $u(x)=u(-x)$?

Answer (score 2):

Define $v(x):=u(x)-u(-x)$: it satisfies the differential equation $-v''(x)+v(x)=0$  and $v(1)=v(-1)=0$. The equation is solvable (the solutions are linear combinations of $t\mapsto e^{-t}$ and $t\mapsto e^{t}$). Now I let you see what happens condiering the boundary conditions.